# Docker Runs MysQL Container With Tables On Terminal, But Not With docker-compose.yml

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

So I'm trying to run a Mysql docker container with some tables setup. It looks like when I do it on the terminal with the following commands, I'm able to access a `mysql` terminal and access created tables. The `Dockerfile`, with `initial.sql`, the file that creates the tables, in the same folder:

```
FROM mysql:5.7.30

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE football_simulation
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password
ENV MYSQL_USER alee
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD anotherpassword
ADD initial.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

Docker commands:

```
docker build -t test/SNAPSHOT .
docker run --name footysimdb -p3308:3306 -d test/SNAPSHOT
docker exec -it footysimdb /bin/bash
```

Login to mysql terminal and access tables:

```
mysql -ualee -panotherpassword
use football_simulation;
show tables;
```

This is fine. I'm trying to simplify this by using `docker-compose.yml` now. However, running `docker-compose up` on this `docker-compose.yml` in the same directory does not work:

```
version: '3'

services:

        mysql-development:
                image: mysql:5.7.30
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
                        MYSQL_DATABASE: football_simulation
                        MYSQL_USER: alee
                        MYSQL_PASSWORD: anotherpassword
                ports:
                - "3308:3306"
                volumes:
                        - initial.sql  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

        admin:
                image: adminer
                ports:
                - "8080:8080"
```

The database `football_simulation` is accessible on port 8080 but the tables do not show up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try changing volumes to `./initial.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial.sql` and make sure that your file is in the compose context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the mounting incorrect. First you do not use `:` delimeter. Also the way you are trying to do it looks like `initial.sql` will be interpreted as named volume. If you want to mount single file to a directory `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in the container - you should use bind mounts. It would look like :

```
./initial.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

so `initial.sql` file from the current context will be mounted through bind mount into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory as `initial.sql` file.

You can read about different types of volumes in [offical docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).